# Show windows JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx

i new in JavaFX.
I have a problem, when a view, called another ... i can see items on the desktop.
in other words, to click a button on the a.fxml view, it closes and opens the b.fxml view.
but in this transition, i can see the desktop of windows.
is possible what this may not happen ??

```
   Stage stage = new Stage();

        stage.setFullScreen(true);            
        Pane myPane = null;
        FXMLLoader fxmlLoader;
        fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource(rutaAbrir));
        myPane = (Pane)fxmlLoader.load();  

        Scene scene = new Scene(myPane);            
        stage.setScene(scene);            

        General controller = (General) fxmlLoader.getController();
        controller.setPrevStage(stage);             
        stage.show();
```

Thanks.

Comment: Can you add images supporting your question? As the question itself is not self-sufficient to understand about the problem.

Comment: Hi  @ItachiUchiha thanks for help me, With an image is hard to explain...But the problem is, when from the file a.fxml call the file b.fxml, during this change of view, we see what is on your computer desktop.It is a little cleare?? Thanks...